# Flipping bits in nested lists

Tags: python-3.x, mutation

I have a project wherein I have to use bit-flip mutation of genetic algorithm.

The code I have so far looks like this:

```
def mutation(pop, mr):
    for i in range(len(pop)):
        if (random.random() < mr):
            if (pop[i] == 1):
                pop[i] = 0
            else:
                pop[i] = 1
        else:
            pop[i] = pop[i]
    return pop

mut = mutation(populations, 0.3)
print(mut)
```

For example, I have the following (depending on my project, `populations` can look like `populations_1` or `populations_2`):

```
populations_1 = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0]] 
populations_2 = [[1], [1], [0], [1]]
```

What I am doing is assigning random generated numbers to elements in `populations` and check if it is less than `mutation rate`. If it is, then `bit-flip mutation` will happen, if not, it will `remain` as it is. For the case of `populations_1`, if `populations_1 index 2` is less than mutation rate, then it should become `[1, 0]`. For `populations_2 index 3`, it should become `[0]` if it is less than mutation rate. This is the objective of the `mutation function`.

Can anyone help me with turning the code I have so far to adapt situations like in populations_1? I think the code I have so far only works for populations_2.

Any help/suggestion/readings would be very much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what would happen for `population_1` index 2, where the value are `[1,1]`. In this case they should become `[0,0]`?

Comment: @DavideBrex if it satisfies the condition, then it should. Same goes for [0, 0].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions to do what you want. The values in `pop` are updated only if `r<mr`. To update them, you can iterate over each element (`a`) in list `pop[i]`, and if `a == 0` it becomes 1, otherwise 0. See the code below:

```
def mutation(pop, mr):
    for i in range(len(pop)):
        r = random.random()
        print(r) # you can remove this line, it is only for testing
        if r < mr:
            pop[i] = [1 if a == 0  else 0 for a in pop[i]]
    return pop
```

**Test 1:**

```
populations_1 = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0,0]] 
mut = mutation(populations_1, 0.3)
print(mut)

#random number for each iteration
0.3952226177233832
0.11290933711515283
0.08131952363738537
0.8489702326753509
0.9598842135077205
#output:
[[1, 0], [0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 0]]
```

**Test 2:**

```
populations_2 = [[1], [1], [0], [1]]
mut = mutation(populations_2, 0.3)
print(mut)


0.3846024893833684
0.7680389523799874
0.19371896835988422
0.008814288533701364
[[1], [1], [1], [0]]
```

Comment: for population_1 index 1, it should be the case if it satisfies the condition for mutation. Same goes for [0, 0] (should be [1, 1] if generated random is less than mr.

Comment: Thank you for this! Will try to understand what is happening with the code you presented.

Comment: I updated the answer, and now I will explain the code in one minute

Comment: thank you for the explanation. Appreciate it big time!